# How many client are looking my live event?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video-streaming, flash-media-server

I have live event in Flash Media Server 4.5.

Now I want to show live viewer to them.

Please advise me to show live viewer number to my clients.

Answer (score 0):

In your .asc file on the server, make a counter that increments each time an `onConnect` event happens, and decrements each time a `onDisconnect` event happens.

Then make a client method to periodically get this number.

[This might help.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/adobemediaserver/ssaslr/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11aff5ba-7f8bSSASLR.2.3.html)

Also, you should really accept some answers to your questions.

Comment: I have some cameras for publish video on the FMS. So I like to show to viewer how many view of each camera.
Above solution fine when I want to calculate total client connected to my APPLICATION not each webcam (50 webcam of 50 live event on once application) etc.

Comment: @M.Yazdian Then do the same thing. Use the API to send a "publishing webcam connected" message to the server, then listen for that message, and use that to increment the counter

Comment: Try `getLiveStreams()` from the Admin console API http://help.adobe.com/en_US/adobemediaserver/adminapi/WSa4cb07693d12388431df580a12a34991ebc-8000.2.3.html

Comment: Other question is: when I stop publishing width ns.close() then publish is stop but in API when I call getLiveStreams for my application I get netstream name that I closed...!!!

So with this Issue I can show to views how many stream is publishing on FMS now.